# Convert column of text to time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named 'slots' with a column whose values are time slots (like 8:00 am, 9:00 am, 9:30 am and so on). But these values are stored as text. I want to convert them to time. I tried the following query

```
UPDATE 'slots' SET 'slot' = STR_TO_TIME('slot', '%h:%i %p')
```

But it gave the following error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''slots' SET 'slot' = STR_TO_TIME('slot', '%h:%i %p')' at line 1

Comment: are you sure about `str_to_time`? maybe [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)?

Comment: My bad. It's str_to_date. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use back ticks

```
UPDATE `slots` SET `slot` = TIME_FORMAT(TIME( STR_TO_DATE( `slot`, '%h:%i %p' ) ), '%h:%i %p' );
```

right now its being used as a literal string instead of a column. back ticks denote a column or tablename not quote marks

Comment: Why even the back ticks? `slot` is not a reserved word, so there shouldn't be a reason for using them.

Comment: Thanks John. It worked. :) But the am/pm thing is now lost. Slots are now displayed as 08:30:00 09:30:00 etc.

Comment: @shree.pat18 just clarifying why to not use a string quote and what the actual syntax is. personal preference I would guess

Comment: @user48234 you want the time with am pm? can you show me an example of it in your question?

Comment: I used this format and got slots as 08:30:00 etc. Used this 'a%h:%i:%s' and the column became blank

Comment: do you want it to be in 24 hour time?

Comment: Nope. I want it in 12 hrs format. I had it in the desired format when it was text string. But STR_TO_TIME changes that.

Comment: 12hr format is same as am/pm, right? If not, I want it in am/pm format

Comment: no i mean do you want to store the date with time and 'am' or 'pm' in the actual tables? or just with the time?

Comment: I want am/pm to be stored

Comment: @user48234 yup :) please accept the answer when you can :)